# returning null user back from function

Tags: sql, flutter

I am working on Login page with Local db SQL in flutter.

The page isn't creating a SQL table and returning null user, thus showing the snackbar "wrong email".

I have tried to debug but can't find the solution as i am pretty new at this.
This is my sign up page:

```
   class _RegisterState extends State<Register> {

   DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper();

TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController mobileController = TextEditingController();

Future<User> _loginUser(String email,String mobile) async{
  User saveUser = User.fromMapObject({
    email:"hfah@gmail.com",
    mobile:"1432567890"

  });
  await db.saveUser(saveUser).then((val) async {
    if(val == 1){
      User user = await db.loginUser(email, mobile);
      return user;
    }
  });
}


final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
final scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final bgColor = const Color(0xFF4b0081);

return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
  backgroundColor: bgColor,
  key: scaffoldKey,
  body: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Image(
        image: AssetImage("assets/newlogo2.png"),
        width: 200,
        height: 50,
      ),

      Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:20.0, right: 20, left: 20),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Mobile No",
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                ),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() => mob = val);
                },
                controller: emailController,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
              TextFormField(
                validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Enter an Email' : null,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Email ID",
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                ),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
                onChanged: (val){
                  setState(() => email = val);
                },
                controller: mobileController,

              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
              RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Text(
                  'Register',
                  style: TextStyle(color: bgColor),
                ),
                onPressed: () async {
                 User user = await _loginUser(emailController.text, mobileController.text);
                  if(user != null){
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute<Null>(
                        builder: (BuildContext context){
                          return new Home(
                            user:user,
                          );
                        }
                    ));
                  }else{
                    scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
                        SnackBar(content: Text("Wrong email"),)
                      );

                  }
                },
                splashColor: Colors.grey,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 12.0,),
              Text(
                error,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    fontSize: 14.0
                ),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                color: bgColor,
                child: Text(
                  'Back to Sign In',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                onPressed: () async {
                  setState(() {
                    //widget.toggleView();
                  },);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),

);
}
```

This is DatabaseHelper class

```
class DatabaseHelper{
   static final DatabaseHelper _instance = new DatabaseHelper.internal();
   factory DatabaseHelper() => _instance;

  static Database _db;

  String colemail = 'emial_id';
  String tablename = 'User';
   String colMobile = 'mobild_no';


  Future<Database> get db async{
    if(_db != null) return _db;
    _db = await initDb();
    return _db;
   }

   DatabaseHelper.internal();

   initDb() async{
     io.Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
     String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "main.db");
     var theDb = await openDatabase(path,version:1,onCreate: _onCreate);
    return theDb;
   }


  void _onCreate(Database db,int version) async{
    await db.execute("""
     CREATE TABLE User(
        user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        email_id TEXT,
        mobile_no TEXT
       )""");
    print("Table created");
   }

  Future<int> saveUser(User user) async{
      var dbClient = await db;
      int res = await dbClient.insert(tablename, user.toMap());
      return res;
  }



  Future<User> loginUser(String email,String mobile) async{
      var dbClient = await db;
      String sql = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE email_id = '$email' AND 
         mobile_no = '$mobile' ";
      var result = await dbClient.rawQuery(sql);
      if(result.length == 0) return null;

       return User.fromMapObject(result.first);
   }
}
```

And this is User class

```
class User{
    int _user_id;
    String email_id;
    String mobile_no;

   User(this.email_id,this.mobile_no,this._user_id);

   String get emailID => email_id;
   String get mobileNO => mobile_no;
   int get user_id =>_user_id;

 set emailID(String newMail){
     this.email_id = newMail;
   }

 set mobileNO(String newMob){
    this.mobile_no = newMob;
 }

 Map <String,dynamic> toMap(){
   return {
     'email_id': email_id,
     'mobile_no': mobile_no,
     'user_id':_user_id
   };
 }

 User.fromMapObject(dynamic map){
     this.email_id = map['email_id'];
     this.mobile_no = map['mobile_no'];
     this._user_id = map['user_id'];
 }
}
```

Please help !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `_RegisterState` class, I don't see if you instantiated `DatabaseHelper db;` so `db` is `null` and you are trying to invoke `saveUser` on `null` instance variable in following code

```dart
await db.saveUser(saveUser).then((val) async {
    if(val == 1){
      User user = await db.loginUser(email, mobile);
      return user;
    }
});
```

Replace this

```dart
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Wrong email"),));
```

with

```dart
scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Wrong email")));
```

Comment: I have instantiated it before TextEditingController

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: You are not initializing db variable in _RegisterState class but you are doing some instantiation in DatabaseHelper class. Try to search db object in _RegisterState class. Please share the complete code or github URL of the code.

Comment: Ok got it. But writing DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(); solved the error and i am getting one exception: throw FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[ ErrorSummary( 'Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.' ),

Comment: This has solved the error but its not signing in i.e its showing the snackbar "Wrong email"always

Comment: Probably because you don't have anything in db and await _loginUser(emailController.text, mobildController.text) might be returning null. You need to debug it.

Comment: Okay will check on that. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You just need to instantiate db:

```
class _RegisterState extends State<Register> {
   DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper();
   ....
}
```

For the Snackbar error, replace this code:

```
else{
   Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(content: Text("Wrong email"),)
   );
}
```

with:

```
else{
   globalKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(content: Text("Wrong email"),)
   );
}
```

Comment: I am getting an exception : throw FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[  ErrorSummary(
        'Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.'
      ),

Comment: Update it the answer to fix your additional error. You just need to use the global key initialized in the top of your code to call show the SnackBar: globalKey.currentState